# После отправки текста из TinyMCE сохранять пустые строки

Tags: html, tinymce

Я использую редактор `TinyMCE` на своём сайте.
Когда я пишу статью, и делаю пустую строку - отступ, то `TinyMCE` это реализует через

```
<p></p>
```

либо в зависимости от ситуации это может быть

```
<p><span style="color:red"></span></p>
```

или например

```
<p><strong></strong></p>
```

Если я на сайте вывожу текст какой мне возвращает `TinyMCE` то у меня все пустые строки - перевод каретки просто не отображаются и выкидываются, это стандартное поведение `HTML` как я понимаю.

Вопрос такой, как мне сделать так что бы то что я вывожу на сайт выглядело также как то что я ввожу в `TinyMCE`?

Как я пытался сделать - на сервере заменять `<p></p>` на `<p>&nbsp;</p>` но не сработало, так как пустая строка в `TinyMCE`, как я писал выше может быть разной.

Как я знаю внутри себя `TinyMCE` такие в такие строчки помещает `<br data-mce-bogus="1">` но в ответ на сервер их не выдаёт, может быть можно как-то его заставить их выдавать?

Comment: А как вам это удалось? мне сохраняет `<p>&nbsp;</p>`

Comment: @splash58 Это вам сам TinyMCE на сервер возвращает при введение пустой строки?

Comment: да. Может, какие-то настройки бывают. но мне кажется, я все по умолчанию подключал

Comment: @splash58 Вы через TextArea подключаете?

Comment: конечно. могу полезть найти опции запуска

Comment: @splash58 Да, буду рад.

Comment: Вот тут выложил. уже не помню, что там делал. но вроде, ничего такого  - https://eval.in/794194 Ну да, еще забираю я яваскриптом, но не думаю, что в этом разница

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58726/discussion-between---and-splash58).

Answer (score 0):

Так как я пишу на C# то решение выбрал такое. После отправки сообщения оно парситься и все эллементы типа `<p><b></b></p>` преобразуется к виду с `<p><b><br class="breakline" /></b></p>`. То есть в центр добавляется тег `<br>`. Вот код алгоритма. Для парсинга используется библиотека AngleSharp.

```
string ReplaceVoidParagraphs(string html)
{
     HtmlParser parser = new HtmlParser();
     IHtmlDocument doc = parser.Parse(html);
     var ps = doc.QuerySelectorAll("p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6");
     foreach(var p in ps)
     {
         DetectVoidParagraph(doc,p);
     }
     return doc.Body.InnerHtml;
}

readonly string[] voidptags = { "p","h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6","span","b","i","strong","em" };

void DetectVoidParagraph(IHtmlDocument doc,IElement ell)
{
    if (!voidptags.Contains(ell.TagName.ToLower()))
         return;
    if(ell.Children.Length == 0 && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ell.TextContent))
    {
        var br = doc.CreateElement("br");
        br.ClassName = "breakline";
        ell.AppendChild(br);
        return;
    }
    if(ell.Children.Length == 1)
    {
        DetectVoidParagraph(doc,ell.Children[0]);
        return;
    }
    return;
}
```